# Adding a func never called improves behavior?

Tags: go

The code below produces undesirable

> [20010101 20010102].

When uncommenting the String func it produces better (but not my implementation):

> [{20010101 1.5} {20010102 2.5}]

However that String func is never called.
I see that Date in DateValue is anonymous and therefore `func (Date) String` is being used by DateValue.

So my questions are:

1) Is this a language issue, a `fmt.Println` implementation issue, or
   something else? Note: if I switch from:

```
func (*DateValue) String() string
```

to

```
func (DateValue) String() string
```

my function is at least called and panic ensues. So if I really want my method called I could do that, but assume DateValue is really a very large object which I only want to pass by reference.

2) What is a good strategy for mixing anonymous fields with
   functionality like Stringer and json encoding that use reflection
   under the covers? For example adding a String or MarshalJSON method
   for a type that happens to be used as an anonymous field can cause
   strange behavior (like you only print or encode part of the whole).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Date int64

func (d Date) String() string {
    t := time.Unix(int64(d),0).UTC()
    return fmt.Sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", t.Year(), int(t.Month()), t.Day())
}

type DateValue struct {
    Date 
    Value float64
}

type OrderedValues []DateValue

/*
// ADD THIS BACK and note that this is never called but both pieces of
// DateValue are printed, whereas, without this only the date is printed
func (dv *DateValue) String() string {
    panic("Oops")
    return fmt.Sprintf("DV(%s,%f)", dv.Date, dv.Value )
}
*/

func main() {
    d1, d2 := Date(978307200),Date(978307200+24*60*60)
    ov1 := OrderedValues{{ d1, 1.5 }, { d2, 2.5 }}
    fmt.Println(ov1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've passed in a slice of DateValues and not DateValue pointers. Since you've defined the String method for `*DataValue`, `*DateValue` is what fulfills the Stringer interface. This also prevents DateValue from fulfilling the Stringer interface via its anonymous Date member, because only one of either the value type (`DateValue`) or the pointer type (`*DateValue`) can be used to fulfill an interface. So, when fmt.Println is printing the contents of the slice, it sees that the elements are not Stringers, and uses the default struct formatting instead of the method you defined, giving `[{20010101 1.5} {20010102 2.5}]`.

You can either make OrderedValues a `[]*DateValue` or define `func (dv DateValue) String() string` instead of the pointer version.

Comment: Thanks. Useful points - would like more on (2). On (1) I don't want to use (*T) say for performance. Why should client choice of []T vs []*T change behavior when choice of T vs *T does not w.r.t. fmt.Println(). That is fmt.Println(DateValue{ Date(978307200), 1}) vs fmt.Println(&DateValue{ Date(978307200), 1}) both work as desired. So, c(sh)ouldn't Println, with all the reflective powers, do the desired thing with the slice. Aside from that, I'm now afraid to throw in String/MarshalJSON in the presence of anonymous for fear of losing existing functionality (like c++ slicing).

Comment: @user1338952 I'm not seeing both of those Println calls working as desired: http://play.golang.org/p/Pz7J581xnl . If I delete the `func (d *DateValue) String()` method, they all print just the date, and if I change it to `func (d DateValue) String()`, they all print the thing we want (which is what I expected).

Comment: You are right. My point is print([]T) differs from print([]*T), but print(T{}) is same as print(&T{}). I feel I should get to choose receiver (d*DateValue) or (d DateValue) and it not affect results. I also think its an issue with fmt not doing the right thing. In following example I mock what I think println c(sh)ould do here (very poor man's proof of concept): http://play.golang.org/p/i_lxXAqlKC

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @SteveM said, I distilled it to a simpler test case:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Fooable interface {
  Foo()
}

type A int

func (a A) Foo() { }

type B struct {
  A
}

// Uncomment the following method and it will print false
//func (b *B) Foo() { }

func main() {
  var x interface{} = B{}
  _, ok := x.(Fooable)
  fmt.Println(ok) // prints true
}
```

In other words, the `Foo` method is not part of the method set of `B` when the `Foo` method for `*B` is defined.

From reading the spec, I don't see a clear explanation of what is happening. The closest part seems to be in the section on [selectors](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors):

> For a value x of type T or *T where T is not an interface type, x.f
>   denotes the field or method at the shallowest depth in T where there
>   is such an f.

The only way I can see this explaining what is going on is if when it is looking for a method `Foo` at shallowest depth in `B`, it takes into consideration the methods for `*B` too, for some reason (even though we are considering type `B` not `*B`); and the `Foo` in `*B` is indeed shallower than the `Foo` in `A`, so it takes that one as the candidate; and then it sees that that `Foo` doesn't work, since it's in `*B` and not `B`, so it gets rid of `Foo` altogether (even though there is a valid one inherited from `A`).

If this is indeed what is going on, then I agree with the OP in that this is very counter-intuitive that *adding* a method to `*B` would have the reverse consequence of *removing* a method from `B`.

Maybe someone more familiar with Go can clarify this.

Comment: When you define Foo explicitly, the implicit definition goes away. This is just a consequence of not being able to define the same method on both the pointer and value type: http://play.golang.org/p/SpkghJdUEl

Comment: @SteveM: but where does it say that in the spec?

Comment: "The method set of any other type T consists of all methods with receiver type T. The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T). … In a method set, each method must have a unique method name." So, if I've got a method on T, I can't also define a same-named method on *T. http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets

Comment: @SteveM: but that doesn't say that if I have a method on *T, that I can't have the same method on T

Comment: I'm not sure that is in the spirit of the spec, but you'll always get the error for the *T method set, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @SteveM: "In a method set, each method must have a unique method name" The problem is, the definition of the method set is confusing. In the "Method sets" section, it says "Further rules apply to structs containing anonymous fields, as described in the section on struct types." From the "Struct types" section, "If S contains an anonymous field T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T." ...

Comment: @SteveM: (continued) However, having a method in an anonymous field does not prevent the "uniqueness" of a method with the same name in the struct, so some mechanism must prevent the method from being included in the struct's method set, or something. From the definition, it seems that this could happen if the method was not "promoted". However, "promoted" is defined as "is called promoted if x.f is a legal selector that denotes that field or method f. " So it depends on whether `x.f` is legal, which seems like a circular definition to me.

Comment: Confusing. I'm not clear on what absence of method from method set means if you can still invoke that method on a value. In this example (without any anonymous) b1 is *NOT* Fooable but b1.Foo() is fine. http://play.golang.org/p/Y2_KWOOgUK